# A Custom Range Partitioner

Tags: c#

*Terminology usage*: I will use chunk, page, partition, or subrange interchangeably.

I frequently use and promote using the `System.Collections.Concurrent.Partitioner` class ([see link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.create?view=net-6.0#System_Collections_Concurrent_Partitioner_Create_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_)).  For my particular usage, I always use it for a full indexed collection, i.e. `IList<T>`.  Sometimes I may use it for single-threaded processing lists with fixed range size per chunk, or I may process in parallel threads where I care more about the number of chunks rather than a specific range size.

Recently I posted an answer using `Partitioner` to this [CR question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/270338/sum-of-2-arrays-using-multi-threading/270355#270355).  However, it caused me to think of ways I could enhance a partitioner customized more to my needs and preferred usage.

For starters, I wish the boring tuple property names of `Item1` and `Item2` had more descriptive names such as `FromInclusive` and `ToExclusive`.

For logging purposes, it would be nice sometimes to know what chunk number I am currently processing.  There could be some other nice things to know such as how many total chunks there are or perhaps whether I am on the last chunk.

I almost always work with an item count, meaning the overall range is from 0 to `item count – 1`.  But the manner in how those chunks are formed and how many chunks there will be depends upon whether I pass in a range size, or a desired chunk count.  With `Partitioner`, if I want a specific chunk count, I must first use my desired chunk count to determine the applicable range size, which is what `Partitioner` is expecting.

**CLASS PartitionedIndexRange**

I am most interested in feedback or a review of this class.

```
public class PartitonedIndexRange
{
    private PartitonedIndexRange(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive, int partitionIndex, int partitionsCount)
    {
        this.FromInclusive = fromInclusive;
        this.ToExclusive = toExclusive;
        this.PartitionIndex = partitionIndex;
        this.PartitionsCount = partitionsCount;
    }

    public int FromInclusive { get; }
    public int ToExclusive { get; } = -1;
    public int PartitionIndex { get; } = -1;
    public int PartitionsCount { get; }

    public int LastPartitionIndex => PartitionsCount - 1;
    public bool IsFirstPartition => PartitionIndex == 0;
    public bool IsLastPartition => PartitionIndex == LastPartitionIndex;
    public int Size => ToExclusive - FromInclusive;

    public static void CheckCannotBeNegative(string name, int value)
    {
        if (value < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(name, $"{name} cannot be negative.");
        }
    }
    public static void CheckMustBePositive(string name, int value)
    {
        if (value <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(name, $"{name} must be greater than 0.");
        }
    }
    public static void Check2CannotBeLessThan1(string name1, int value1, string name2, int value2)
    {
        if (value2 < value1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(name2, $"{name2} cannot be less than {name1}.");
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<PartitonedIndexRange> GetPartitionsByRangeSize(int itemCount, int rangeSize)
    {
        CheckCannotBeNegative(nameof(itemCount), itemCount);
        CheckMustBePositive(nameof(rangeSize), rangeSize);
        if (itemCount == 0)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        int partitionCount = GetChunkSize(itemCount, rangeSize);

        foreach (var partition in GetPartitions(0, itemCount, partitionCount, rangeSize))
        {
            yield return partition;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<PartitonedIndexRange> GetPartitionsByRangeSize(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive, int rangeSize)
    {
        CheckCannotBeNegative(nameof(fromInclusive), fromInclusive);
        Check2CannotBeLessThan1(nameof(fromInclusive), fromInclusive, nameof(toExclusive), toExclusive);
        CheckMustBePositive(nameof(rangeSize), rangeSize);
        if (toExclusive == fromInclusive)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        int partitionCount = GetChunkSize(toExclusive - fromInclusive, rangeSize);
        foreach (var partition in GetPartitions(fromInclusive, toExclusive, partitionCount, rangeSize))
        {
            yield return partition;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<PartitonedIndexRange> GetPartitionsByPartitionCount(int itemCount, int partitionCount)
    {
        CheckCannotBeNegative(nameof(itemCount), itemCount);
        CheckMustBePositive(nameof(partitionCount), partitionCount);
        if (itemCount == 0)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        int rangeSize = GetChunkSize(itemCount, partitionCount);
        foreach (var partition in GetPartitions(0, itemCount, partitionCount, rangeSize))
        {
            yield return partition;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<PartitonedIndexRange> GetPartitionsByPartitionCount(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive, int partitionCount)
    {
        CheckCannotBeNegative(nameof(fromInclusive), fromInclusive);
        Check2CannotBeLessThan1(nameof(fromInclusive), fromInclusive, nameof(toExclusive), toExclusive);
        CheckMustBePositive(nameof(partitionCount), partitionCount);
        if (toExclusive == fromInclusive)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        int rangeSize = GetChunkSize(toExclusive - fromInclusive, partitionCount);
        foreach (var partition in GetPartitions(fromInclusive, toExclusive, partitionCount, rangeSize))
        {
            yield return partition;
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<PartitonedIndexRange> GetPartitions(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive, int partitionCount, int rangeSize)
    {
        int inclusiveStart = fromInclusive;
        for (int partitionIndex = 0; partitionIndex < partitionCount; partitionIndex++)
        {
            bool isLast = (partitionIndex + 1) == partitionCount;
            int exclusiveEnd = isLast ? toExclusive : inclusiveStart + rangeSize;
            var partition = new PartitonedIndexRange(inclusiveStart, exclusiveEnd, partitionIndex, partitionCount);
            yield return partition;
            inclusiveStart = exclusiveEnd;
        }
    }

    private static int GetChunkSize(int itemCount, int inputSize)
    {
        // <quote>Context means everything.</quote>
        // If inputSize is a Range Size, then outputSize is the Partition Count
        // If inputSize is a Partition Count, then outputSize is the Range Size
        int outputSize = itemCount / inputSize;
        return (itemCount % inputSize == 0) ? outputSize : 1 + outputSize;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Partition[{PartitionIndex}] Range [{FromInclusive} - {ToExclusive}) Size {Size}";
    }
}
```

I intentionally made the constructor private restricting usage to the static create methods:  `GetPartitionsByRangeSize` and  `GetPartitionsByPartitionCount`.

**STATIC CLASS UsageExample**

Note I am not interested in any feedback or review on the `UsageExample` class.

```
internal static class UsageExample
{
    private static Random _random { get; } = new Random();

    public static void RunSimple()
    {
        // Simple example does not need an actual collection.
        // All we really need is to know the size of a collection.
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("SIMPLE EXAMPLE using itemCount");
        var itemCount = _random.Next(60_000, 200_000);

        var rangeSize = 12_500;
        var partitionsByRangeSize = PartitonedIndexRange.GetPartitionsByRangeSize(itemCount, rangeSize);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"BY RANGE SIZE.  ItemCount={itemCount} RangeSize={rangeSize}");
        foreach (var partition in partitionsByRangeSize)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(partition);
        }

        var partitionCount = 9;
        var partitionsByPartitionCount = PartitonedIndexRange.GetPartitionsByPartitionCount(itemCount, partitionCount);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"BY PARTITION COUNT.  ItemCount={itemCount} PartitionCount={partitionCount}");
        foreach (var partition in partitionsByPartitionCount)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(partition);
        }
    }

    public static void RunSimple2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("SIMPLE EXAMPLE using toInclusive & fromExclusive");

        var fromInclusive = 1_000;
        var toExclusive = 12_500;
        var rangeSize = 1_000;
        var partitionsByRangeSize = PartitonedIndexRange.GetPartitionsByRangeSize(fromInclusive, toExclusive, rangeSize);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"BY RANGE SIZE.  FromInclusive={fromInclusive} ToExclusive={toExclusive} RangeSize={rangeSize}");
        foreach (var partition in partitionsByRangeSize)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(partition);
        }

        var partitionCount = 10;
        var partitionsByPartitionCount = PartitonedIndexRange.GetPartitionsByPartitionCount(fromInclusive, toExclusive, partitionCount);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"BY PARTITION COUNT.  FromInclusive={fromInclusive} ToExclusive={toExclusive} PartitionCount={partitionCount}");
        foreach (var partition in partitionsByPartitionCount)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(partition);
        }
    }

    public static void RunParallel()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("PARALLEL EXAMPLE");
        var arraySize = _random.Next(88_888, 111_111);
        var maxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount + 1;

        var example = SumArray.Create(arraySize, maxDegreeOfParallelism);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"Running multi-threaded for ArraySize={arraySize} MaxDegreeOfParallelism={maxDegreeOfParallelism}");
        Console.WriteLine("Custom partitioner with guaranteed order will be called.");
        Console.WriteLine("Parallel.ForEach order is NOT guaranteed.");
        var elapsed = example.RunMultiThreaded();
        Console.WriteLine($"   Elapsed = {elapsed}");
    }

    private class SumArray
    {
        // Modified my answer from this original Code Review post:
        // https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/270338/sum-of-2-arrays-using-multi-threading/270355#270355

        public int[] ArrayA { get; private set; } = new int[0];
        public int[] ArrayB { get; private set; } = new int[0];
        public int[] ArrayC { get; private set; } = new int[0];

        public int MaxDegreeOfParallelism { get; private set; } = 1;
        public int ArraySize { get; private set; } = 0;

        private SumArray(int size, int maxDegreeOfParallelism)
        {
            // There are probably more checks that could be done but here are the minimum.
            if (size <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(size), "Array size must be greater than 0");
            }
            if (maxDegreeOfParallelism <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxDegreeOfParallelism), "MaxDegreeOfParallelism must be greater than 0");
            }

            // While I could call Initialize() here, my philosophy is that a constructor
            // should do the BARE MINIMUM, which is only to set some properties and
            // then return as quickly as possible.
            // To that end, I mark the constructor as private, and require accessing
            // it via the public Create().

            this.ArraySize = size;
            this.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism;
        }

        public static SumArray Create(int size, int maxDegreeOfParallelism)
        {
            var instance = new SumArray(size, maxDegreeOfParallelism);
            // Initialize is intentionally run after construction.
            instance.Initialize();
            return instance;
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            ArrayA = new int[ArraySize];
            ArrayB = new int[ArraySize];
            ArrayC = new int[ArraySize];

            // Magic number replacements.
            // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)
            // Consider increasing with bigger arrays.
            // Consider making parameters or properties rather than constants.
            const int minA = 1;
            const int maxA = 9999;
            const int minB = 100_000;
            const int maxB = 900_000;

            for (int i = 0; i < ArraySize; i++)
            {
                // Consider increasing the magic num
                ArrayA[i] = _random.Next(minA, maxA);
                ArrayB[i] = _random.Next(minB, maxB);
            }
        }

        public TimeSpan RunSingleThreaded()
        {
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < ArraySize; i++)
            {
                ArrayC[i] = ArrayA[i] + ArrayB[i];

            }
            watch.Stop();
            return watch.Elapsed;
        }

        public TimeSpan RunMultiThreaded()
        {
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            var options = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = MaxDegreeOfParallelism };

            // CUSTOM PARTITIONER CALL HERE
            var partitions = PartitonedIndexRange.GetPartitionsByPartitionCount(ArraySize, MaxDegreeOfParallelism);

            // While the partitioner sends the partitions in order,
            // the task scheduler is not guaranteed to process them in the same order.
            Parallel.ForEach(partitions, options, partition =>
            {
                LockedWriteLine($"   START {partition}");
                for (var i = partition.FromInclusive; i < partition.ToExclusive; i++)
                {
                    ArrayC[i] = ArrayA[i] + ArrayB[i];
                }
                LockedWriteLine($"   END   Partition[{partition.PartitionIndex}]");
            });

            watch.Stop();
            return watch.Elapsed;
        }

        private object _lockObject = new object();
        private void LockedWriteLine(string text)
        {
            // I know Console.WriteLine is supposed to be thread safe,
            // but I am being extra cautious here to remove any doubt.
            lock (_lockObject)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(text);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This requires `using System.Diagnostics ;` for the `Stopwatch`.  There is a subclass named `SumArray`, which is a modified example of the answer I provided to this POST.  The `RunMultiThreaded` method uses the custom partitioner.  I included some `Console.WriteLine` to illustrate when a thread starts and ends, which can produce some very interesting results regarding ordering.

**SAMPLE CONSOLE OUTPUT**

```
SIMPLE EXAMPLE

BY RANGE SIZE.  ItemCount=77032 RangeSize=12500
Partition[0] Range [0 - 12500) Size 12500
Partition[1] Range [12500 - 25000) Size 12500
Partition[2] Range [25000 - 37500) Size 12500
Partition[3] Range [37500 - 50000) Size 12500
Partition[4] Range [50000 - 62500) Size 12500
Partition[5] Range [62500 - 75000) Size 12500
Partition[6] Range [75000 - 77032) Size 2032

BY PARTITION COUNT.  Item Count=77032 PartitionCount=9
Partition[0] Range [0 - 8560) Size 8560
Partition[1] Range [8560 - 17120) Size 8560
Partition[2] Range [17120 - 25680) Size 8560
Partition[3] Range [25680 - 34240) Size 8560
Partition[4] Range [34240 - 42800) Size 8560
Partition[5] Range [42800 - 51360) Size 8560
Partition[6] Range [51360 - 59920) Size 8560
Partition[7] Range [59920 - 68480) Size 8560
Partition[8] Range [68480 - 77032) Size 8552

PARALLEL EXAMPLE

Running multi-threaded for ArraySize=103493 MaxDegreeOfParallelism=7
Custom partitioner with guaranteed order will be called.
Parallel.ForEach order is NOT guaranteed.
   START Partition[0] Range [0 - 14785) Size 14785
   END   Partition[0]
   START Partition[1] Range [14785 - 29570) Size 14785
   START Partition[4] Range [59140 - 73925) Size 14785
   END   Partition[4]
   START Partition[2] Range [29570 - 44355) Size 14785
   END   Partition[1]
   START Partition[6] Range [88710 - 103493) Size 14783
   END   Partition[6]
   START Partition[3] Range [44355 - 59140) Size 14785
   END   Partition[3]
   START Partition[5] Range [73925 - 88710) Size 14785
   END   Partition[5]
   END   Partition[2]
   Elapsed = 00:00:00.0364611
```

Simple Observations: notice the size of the last partition in the Simple example, chunking by Partition Count produces more balanced chunks than by Range Size.

Parallel Observations: although the custom partitioner creates the partitions in a very ordered, sequential manner, the `Parallel.ForEach` does not guarantee the order of processing.  Note that # 2 starts after # 4 but before # 6, 3 and 5, and that # 2 also is the last to complete.  Note as well that # 0 started and ended before the others began.

Granted that’s just from one sample run.  I encourage you to run it several times since the results change.  Here is output from another run.

```
SIMPLE EXAMPLE

BY RANGE SIZE.  ItemCount=130810 RangeSize=12500
Partition[0] Range [0 - 12500) Size 12500
Partition[1] Range [12500 - 25000) Size 12500
Partition[2] Range [25000 - 37500) Size 12500
Partition[3] Range [37500 - 50000) Size 12500
Partition[4] Range [50000 - 62500) Size 12500
Partition[5] Range [62500 - 75000) Size 12500
Partition[6] Range [75000 - 87500) Size 12500
Partition[7] Range [87500 - 100000) Size 12500
Partition[8] Range [100000 - 112500) Size 12500
Partition[9] Range [112500 - 125000) Size 12500
Partition[10] Range [125000 - 130810) Size 5810

BY PARTITION COUNT.  ItemCount=130810 PartitionCount=9
Partition[0] Range [0 - 14535) Size 14535
Partition[1] Range [14535 - 29070) Size 14535
Partition[2] Range [29070 - 43605) Size 14535
Partition[3] Range [43605 - 58140) Size 14535
Partition[4] Range [58140 - 72675) Size 14535
Partition[5] Range [72675 - 87210) Size 14535
Partition[6] Range [87210 - 101745) Size 14535
Partition[7] Range [101745 - 116280) Size 14535
Partition[8] Range [116280 - 130810) Size 14530

PARALLEL EXAMPLE

Running multi-threaded for ArraySize=98424 MaxDegreeOfParallelism=7
Custom partitioner with guaranteed order will be called.
Parallel.ForEach order is NOT guaranteed.
   START Partition[1] Range [14061 - 28122) Size 14061
   START Partition[0] Range [0 - 14061) Size 14061
   START Partition[3] Range [42183 - 56244) Size 14061
   END   Partition[1]
   START Partition[2] Range [28122 - 42183) Size 14061
   END   Partition[3]
   START Partition[4] Range [56244 - 70305) Size 14061
   END   Partition[0]
   START Partition[6] Range [84366 - 98424) Size 14058
   END   Partition[2]
   END   Partition[4]
   END   Partition[6]
   START Partition[5] Range [70305 - 84366) Size 14061
   END   Partition[5]
   Elapsed = 00:00:00.0644807
```

Here is another example of parallel usage where the ***last partition starts before the first one!***

```
PARALLEL EXAMPLE

Running multi-threaded for ArraySize=93916 MaxDegreeOfParallelism=7
Custom partitioner with guaranteed order will be called.
Parallel.ForEach order is NOT guaranteed.
   START Partition[1] Range [13417 - 26834) Size 13417
   START Partition[6] Range [80502 - 93916) Size 13414
   START Partition[3] Range [40251 - 53668) Size 13417
   START Partition[2] Range [26834 - 40251) Size 13417
   START Partition[5] Range [67085 - 80502) Size 13417
   START Partition[4] Range [53668 - 67085) Size 13417
   START Partition[0] Range [0 - 13417) Size 13417
   END   Partition[1]
   END   Partition[6]
   END   Partition[3]
   END   Partition[2]
   END   Partition[5]
   END   Partition[0]
   END   Partition[4]
   Elapsed = 00:00:00.0346445
```

**CONCERNS**

While I like `UsageExample` as a nice way of demonstrating the unpredictable order of parallel tasks, I have little concern about a review of its code.  My primary concern is a review of the `PartitionedIndexRange` class.  So far, I like it enough to have it find a welcome on my developer’s toolkit.  Having meta data about the partition is nice from a logging perspective in my many applications, most of which are Console apps running unattended via Windows Task Scheduler.

I chose to use longer descriptive names for the meta data to clarify the context of the indices.  There are the pair of `FromInclusive` and `ToExclusive`, which do not contain the word “Index” and save for the capitalization match the old partitioner names.  For the meta properties, I could have gone with “Id” or “Index” but chose the longer “PartitionIndex” to be clear.  Ditto for “PartitionCount” instead of “Count”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your approach is simple and straight forward. The overall naming convention is good. Many parts of the class have descriptive naming, and that makes things much easier to understand the class.

The validations methods such as `CheckCannotBeNegative`, `CheckMustBePositive` ..etc. since the actual purpose is to test a value against condition and throw an exception if true, it would be more sensible to include `Throw` in the method's name, such as `ThrowIfNegative` as it would tell what to expect from this method. `CheckMustBePositive` can be also `ThrowIfZeroOrNegative`.

for the actual methods `GetPartitionsByRangeSize` and `GetPartitionsByPartitionCount` they have similar logic, the only difference I see are three values `fromInclusive` , `partitionCount` and `rangeSize`.

So basically, you have two strategies, one using a starting and ending indexes, and the second would be to use a chunk size (which is the `ItemCount`). So, instead of replicating 4 methods, we can do one private method, and recall it with the arguments needed from the public methods instead. This would mean extending `GetChunkSize` with a way to calculate the `partitionCount` and `rangeSize` based on the passed arguments that we did in the public methods.

My theory is to reduce code redundancy and add more maintainability and readibility, which would results with something like this :

```
public static IEnumerable<PartitonedIndexRange> GetPartitionsByPartitionCount(int itemCount, int partitionCount)
{
    return GetPartitionsByPartitionCount(0, itemCount, partitionCount);
}

public static IEnumerable<PartitonedIndexRange> GetPartitionsByPartitionCount(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive, int partitionCount)
{
    return InternalCreatePartitions(fromInclusive, toExclusive, partitionCount, 0);
}

public static IEnumerable<PartitonedIndexRange> GetPartitionsByRangeSize(int itemCount, int rangeSize)
{
    return GetPartitionsByRangeSize(0, itemCount, rangeSize);
}

public static IEnumerable<PartitonedIndexRange> GetPartitionsByRangeSize(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive, int rangeSize)
{
    return InternalCreatePartitions(fromInclusive, toExclusive, 0, rangeSize);
}


private static IEnumerable<PartitonedIndexRange> InternalCreatePartitions(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive, int partitionCount, int rangeSize)
{
    // here we will put the combined logic of the GetPartitionsByRangeSize && GetPartitionsByPartitionCount
}
```

if you see that we passes `0` to some arguments, as a way to determine which part of the arguments should be calculated (or ignored) internally. For instance, if we pass a zero to `rangeSize` then it means we need to calculate the chunk size based on the `partitionCount`, thus, we will have the `rangeSize` calculated. While if we pass zero to the `fromInclusive` this would give us the `ItemCount` since `itemCount = toExclusive`.

based on that, the `GetChunkSize` would be extended to something like this :

```
private static (int PartitionCount, int RangeSize) InternalGetCalculatedChunkSize(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive, int partitionCount, int rangeSize)
{                      
    int calculatedRangeSize = rangeSize;

    int calculatedPartitionSize = partitionCount;

    // if it's a Partition Count then the fromInclusive would be zero.
    int itemCount = toExclusive - fromInclusive;

    // since we passes a zero to one of the operhands (partitionCount OR rangeSize)
    // this shall determines which non-zero part should be used as input size
    int inputSize = Math.Max(calculatedPartitionSize, calculatedRangeSize);
   
    int outputSize = itemCount / (inputSize == 0 ? 1 : inputSize); // extra insurance to prevent from DivideByZeroException

    int chunkSize = (itemCount % inputSize == 0) ? outputSize : 1 + outputSize;

    if (partitionCount == 0)
    {

        calculatedPartitionSize = chunkSize;
    }
    else
    {
        calculatedRangeSize = chunkSize;               
    }

    // if for some reason the calculation resulted a zero or negative
    ThrowIfZeroOrNegative(nameof(calculatedPartitionSize), calculatedPartitionSize);

    ThrowIfZeroOrNegative(nameof(calculatedRangeSize), calculatedRangeSize);

    return (PartitionCount: calculatedPartitionSize, RangeSize: calculatedRangeSize);
}
```

Now, we can do this :

```
private static IEnumerable<PartitonedIndexRangev2> InternalCreatePartitions(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive, int partitionCount, int rangeSize)
{
    ThrowIfNegative(nameof(fromInclusive), fromInclusive);
    
    ThrowIfNegative(nameof(toExclusive), toExclusive);
    
    ThrowIfNegative(nameof(partitionCount), partitionCount);
    
    ThrowIfNegative(nameof(rangeSize), rangeSize);

    if (toExclusive < fromInclusive)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(toExclusive), $"{nameof(toExclusive)} cannot be less than {nameof(fromInclusive)}.");
    }

    // (fromInclusive + toExclusive) == 0 is equivalent to ItemCount == 0 since we passes a zero to fromInclusive.
    if (fromInclusive == toExclusive || (fromInclusive + toExclusive) == 0) 
    { 
        yield break; 
    }

    var chunkSize = InternalGetCalculatedChunkSize(fromInclusive, toExclusive, partitionCount, rangeSize);
    
    foreach (var partition in InternalGetPartitionsIterator(fromInclusive, toExclusive, chunkSize.PartitionCount, chunkSize.RangeSize))
    {
        yield return partition;
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<PartitonedIndexRange> InternalGetPartitionsIterator(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive, int partitionCount, int rangeSize)
{
    int inclusiveStart = fromInclusive;

    for (int partitionIndex = 0; partitionIndex < partitionCount; partitionIndex++)
    {
        bool isLast = (partitionIndex + 1) == partitionCount;

        int exclusiveEnd = isLast ? toExclusive : inclusiveStart + rangeSize;

        var partition = new PartitonedIndexRange(inclusiveStart, exclusiveEnd, partitionIndex, partitionCount);

        yield return partition;

        inclusiveStart = exclusiveEnd;
    }
}
```

With that, the initial theory should work as expected.

The last thing to add, is using `uint` instead of `int` if possible. This would reduce the need of checking for negative integers.

Comment: Thank you for the review.  I like the idea of using `Throw` in the check method names.  The reason I did not use `GetPartitionsByPartitionCount(0, itemCount, partitionCount);` is because the error message should be about `itemCount` and not `fromExclusive`, which is how it would be with yours.  Someone who passed in `itemCount` could be confused as to why the exception is mentioning `fromExclusive`.

Comment: @RickDavin I see now, well, you could add validations at each method, just to verify the values before it's passed to the main method, that should be fine too.

Answer (score 2):

Here'se a small trick how you can make this code nicely fluent and extendable so that anyone can add new factories.

---

Create a *dummy* class with a single property of its own type.

```cs
public sealed class Partitions
{
    public static Partitions? By => default;
}
```

Then rewrite all methods as extensions:

```cs
public static class PartitionFactories
{
    public static IEnumerable<Partition> RangeSize(this Partitions? by, int itemCount, int rangeSize)
    {
        // ..
    }
    
    public static IEnumerable<Partition> Count(this Partitions? by, int fromInclusive, int toExclusive, int partitionCount)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and chain them:

```cs
var x = Partitions.By.RangeSize(100, 5);
```

---

I would also turn the big class into a small `struct`:

```cs
public readonly record struct Partition(int From, int To, int Index, int Count)
{
    public bool IsFirst => Index == 0;
    public bool IsLast => Index == LastIndex;
    public int Size => To - From;
    public int LastIndex => Count - 1;
}
```